# input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span doesnot work in IE8?

Tags: html, css

`input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span` does not work in IE. Actually the style rule is not even seen in the developers tool, when inspect element is done.

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="Hello" id="Hello"/>
<span>Hello</span>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

When the checkbox is checked, I am trying to make the span bold. This is working in Chrome, but not in IE8. Also, o verify why its not working, I was trying to inspect the element, I did find this style rule there. Hope this is clear.

Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: Which class? Your selector has no class in it.

Comment: @Archana Your code does work in IE. See this --> http://jsfiddle.net/ppxpj69x/ . Check this in IE.

Comment: IE8 doesn’t support `:checked`. You can only get around this with JavaScript.

Comment: In regard to your question, something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) may add support for this in non-compliant browsers. It [may not be worth messing with it](http://www.allwebcafe.com/blog/time-to-drop-support-for-ie8/) if it takes more than a quick shim. At this stage, only [10% of your total market uses IE 8](http://www.theie8countdown.com/), with usage dropping every month. Like its predecessors, the vendor itself (Microsoft) is actively working to remove it, so supporting it has little return on the investment of time.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Answer (score 0):

Like it was mentioned, IE8 does not support :checked, thus a solution can be using JavaScript, such as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <style>
        /*
        input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
font-weight:bold;
}*/
    </style>
    <label>
        <input onchange="on_click()" type="checkbox" name="Hello" id="Hello"/>
        <span id ="hello">Hello</span>
    </label>

    <script>
        count = 0;
        function on_click() {
            var hello = "Hello";
            count = count + 1;
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = hello;

            } else {

                document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = hello.bold();
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: What if I more that one checkboxes...? This is just for only one

Answer (score 0):

since you're only option is to do it with javascript,you can do something like this(if you want to use jquery):

```
function checkboxIscheckedHandler(el) {
    var _this = $(el);
    if (_this.checked)
        _this.next('span').css("font-weight", "bold");
    else
        _this.next('span').css("font-weight", "normal");
}
```

and you just add this function to every checkbox's `onchange` property like this

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="checkboxIscheckedHandler(this)" name="Hello" id="Hello"/>
```

Comment: tell me if you want the pure javascript solution